# fix a delay issue when switching from one window to another using TKinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I'm developing a GUI using TKinter for a kiosk based application and I've developed a basic code which switches from one window to another on button click.

Below is the code I've tried and it runs successfully. However I'm finding some delay issues when switching from one window to another. When user presses the button on the root window, there is sufficient amount of delay occurred before second screen display. I've tested it step by step and realised that the way image opened and displayed, it takes sufficient processing time and that creates a delay issues.

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter as tk

from functools import partial
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def test(root):
    root.withdraw()
    master1 = tk.Toplevel()
    coverPhoto = Image.open('/home/pi/x.jpg')
    coverPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(coverPhoto)
    lblBackground = Label(master1, width=ws, height=hs, image=coverPhoto)
    lblBackground.photo = coverPhoto
    lblBackground.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
    master1.config(width=ws, height=hs)
    master1.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    master1.mainloop()
    return


root = tk.Tk()
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()

root.title(' Sample test ')

idPhoto = Image.open('/home/pi/x.jpg')
idPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(idPhoto)
lblImg = Label(root, width=ws, height=hs, image=idPhoto)
lblImg.photo = idPhoto
lblImg.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

startImg = Image.open('/home/pi/y.jpg'  )
startImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(startImg)
button = tk.Button(lblImg, image=startImg, highlightthickness=1, bd=0, command=lambda : test(root)) 
button.image = startImg
button.place(x=0, y=hs - 120, width=ws, height=120)
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.config(width=ws, height=hs)
root.mainloop()
```

Is there any other calling way which will take less time in processing? I want a smooth go when changing from one screen to another?

Comment: Create your frames first, then swap them instead of reloading images, and recreating everything each time.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with it, but you shouldn't be calling `mainloop` inside of `test`. You already have a `mainloop` running, you shouldn't have two.

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating a new toplevel window rather than replacing the contents of the root window?

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you for looking out into my problem. This is just a small part of the whole code and in total we've 6-7 display screen and in every window, different image is displayed with different function. If this is not a good way, then would be great, if you can help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could load *all* images *before* you start the `mainloop`.

That would of course increase the startup time of the application, but it should reduce window switch times.

**Edit**: Also place all the `ImageTk.PhotoImage` calls *after* `root = tk.Tk()` but before the `mainloop`. That is, take the code for `coverPhoto` out of `test`, and put it between `root` and `mainloop`.

**Edit2:** A white flash when a window closes is probably caused by the relatively slow graphics hardware on the raspberry pi, combined with how X11 works.

Instead of two top-pevel windows, try using a [`tkinter.ttk.Notebook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Notebook) with two "tabs". Hide and unhide the relevant tabs in the *same* X11 window.

Comment: Thank you for the positive response. I am new to GUI programming. A reference to some sample code would definitely help me.

Comment: @PriyaGarg Just move all the `Image.open` calls to just before `root = tk.Tk()`...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried calling the Image.open function before root function. But it doesn't make a much difference in the delay. :(

Comment: Hi, I am sorry to bother you again, thank you for your help. I can see the difference in window switching time but still a fraction of millisec time is there and I can see this. Maybe, we can't reduce it much. I am having one more issue: On my second screen (test), there is timer and when this timer expires, it will return to mainscreen again. But when it returns, there is a white flash window displays then it comes back to mainscreen. Did you find this behavior of GUI earlier in your experience?

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I will give it a try and provide you my results. :)